# Como controlar transações em Node.js?

Tags: node.js, transações

Estou iniciando em Node.js e procurei bastante sobre **controle de transações**, porém não encontrei nada parecido com o que estou acostumado em Java.

Primeiro vou esclarecer o que quero dizer com controle de transações:
Imagine uma operação complexa onde a lógica de negócio esteja separada em 2 ou mais serviços (ou módulos ou arquivos, etc), cada serviço interage com o banco e pode fazer alterações. Se ocorrer algum erro em qualquer dos serviços, tudo deve ser desfeito (rollback) para que não fiquem dados inconsistentes no banco.

Um exemplo clássico de onde o controle de transação é importante, é uma transferência bancária, são necessários duas operações, débito em uma conta e crédito em outra, ou ambas ocorrem com sucesso ou nenhuma pode ser efetuada.

Em java, frameworks como o Spring suportam o controle de transações de forma muito simples e transparente para o desenvolvedor, ou seja, fazendo as configurações corretas, não é preciso mais se preocupar com isto, o framework faz todo o controle: Inicia a transação e efetua o commit ou roolback conforme necessário, mesmo quando a lógica está distribuída em vários serviços.

Procurei algum framework que fizesse o mesmo em Node.js, porém o mais próximo disso que achei foram as 'Promises', que basicamente permitem executar várias operações de banco de forma ordenada e em caso de erro efetuar o rollback, entretanto quando a lógica está distribuída em vários serviços as Promises não são suficientes.

A dúvida é: existe algum framework ou técnica para Node.js capaz de fazer este controle ou simplesmente Node.js não é uma boa opção para aplicações que necessitem controle transacional?

Estou utilizando banco de dados MySQL e a lib mysql2 (https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2)

Comment: encontrei este projeto: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-bemis, caso seja útil.

Comment: O node-bemis até controla transações, mas de forma manual, é parecido com o que as Promises oferecem...

Comment: qual é o banco de dados que está a usar?

Comment: Isto vai depender da library utilizada para realizar as consultas, e consequentemente do banco de dados utilizado... atualiza a pergunta com estas informações que será mais fácil de alguém responder